# Solve the equation $|2x-1| -|x+5| = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> Problem : Solve the equation $|2x-1| - |x+5| = 3$

In my attempt to solve the problem, I only manage to get one of the solutions.

*Attempted Solution*

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|x|-|y| & \leq |x-y| \\
\implies |2x-1| - |x+5| & \leq |(2x-1)-(x+5)| \\
\implies 3 &\leq |x-6| \\
\implies 3 &= |x-6| \\
\implies (x = 9) \ & \lor \ (x= 3 \ (\text{Reject})) \\
\implies x &= 9
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

However plugging the correct solution set to this equation is $x \in \{-\frac{7}{3}, 9\}$. Why does my attempted solution, not reach $-\frac{7}{3}$, as one of the possible solutions? Furthermore, how would you go about solving a problem of this nature?

Comment: $3 \leq |x-6|$ does not imply $3=|x-6|$.Try to distinguish different cases, to get rid of the absolute values. Then you will just get linear equations. For example, if $x>\frac{1}{2}$, then $2x-1-x+5=5$. I am sure you can solve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $|x|=\begin{cases}x&\text{if}~x\geq 0\\ -x&\text{if}~x<0\end{cases}$

Now, we attempt to rewrite the original expression *without* absolute value signs.  To do so, we ask ourselves when do we need to change the sign for each?  On what regions will we need to change the sign of $|2x-1|$?  The sign of $|x+5|$?

$2x-1<0$ when $x<\frac{1}{2}$.

$x+5<0$ when $x<-5$

We see then that the expression can be written without absolute value signs if broken into the following three regions: case 1:$x<-5$, case 2: $-5\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$, and case 3: $\frac{1}{2}\leq x$

$|2x-1|-|x+5| = \begin{cases} -(2x-1)-(-(x+5))&\text{when}~x<-5\\
-(2x-1)-(x+5)&\text{when}~-5\leq x<\frac{1}{2}\\
(2x-1)-(x+5)&\text{when}~\frac{1}{2}\leq x\end{cases}$

Setting each of these equal to three and solving for $x$ individually, and then checking that such a value for $x$ lies within its respective region will finish the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Because $|2x-1|-|x+5|$ is also $\leq |(x+5) - (2x-1)|$.  (Multiplying through by $-1$ doesn't change the absolute value...)

The generic method is this:

- $x+5$ is nonnegative for $x \geq -5$ and negative for $x < -5$.
- $2x-1$ is nonnegative for $x \geq 1/2$ and negative for $x < 1/2$.
- On the interval $(-\infty,-5)$, both are negative, so we solve  $$ |2x-1|-|x+5| = -(2x-1)--(x+5) = -x + 6 = 3  \text{,}  $$ so $x = 3$, but this is not in $(-\infty, -5)$, so we reject it.
- On the interval $[-5,1/2)$, we solve $$ |2x-1|-|x+5| = -(2x-1)-(x+5) = -3x - 4 = 3  \text{,}  $$ so $x = -7/3$, which is in $[-5,1/2)$.
- On the interval $[1/2,\infty)$, we solve $$ |2x-1|-|x+5| = (2x-1)-(x+5) = x - 6 = 3  \text{,}  $$ so $x = 9$, which is in $[1/2,\infty)$.

So the solution set is $\{-7/3,9\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions $2x-1$ and $x+5$ can take on positive, zero, and negative values.

You considered the case for which both expressions were positive.

If $-5 < x < 1/2$, then one is positive and one is negative, so your equation for those values of $x$ becomes:

$$(1-2x) - (x+5) = 3$$

If $x < -5$ then both expressions are negative and you have

$$(1-2x) - (-x -5) = 3$$

This equation doesn't produce a valid solution, because even though $x=3$ solves the equation, it's not less than $-5$.

The equation above, though, has $x = -7/3$ as a solution, and as it's between $1/2$ and $-5$, it also solve the original equation.